# Ruby: dereferencing pointer

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pointers

How can I dereference a pointer in Ruby?

I'm using FFI to call some C/C++ DLL function. One of these function returns an array of ints (int*).

```
extern "C" WIN32PROJECT3_API int* TestData()
{
    int* v;

    v = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* 1000);

    v[3] = 123456;

    return v;
}
```

I've got the pointer in Ruby but when I try to do

```
v = TestModule.TestData();
puts v[3]
```

what I get is:

```
#<FFI::Pointer address=0x700f5e>
```

which is perfectly fine as this is the actual value of the pointer. I only need to derefence it to get the value "123456"

Comment: oops, sorry for the typo, I meant array of ints

Comment: Do you actually want to use Ruby?  This and another question yesterday feel like you're trying to turn Ruby into C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`read_int`](http://ruby-doc.com/gems/docs/f/ffi-ffi-0.5.0/FFI/Pointer.html#method-i-read_int)

Example:

```
v = TestModule.TestData();
puts v[3].read_int
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [AbstractMemory#get_array_of_int32](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/AbstractMemory) method.

> #get_array_of_int32(offset, length) ⇒ Array < Fixnum >
>
> Get 32-bit ints in memory from offset `offset`.

```
v = TestModule.TestData.get_array_of_int32(0, 1000) # first convert your memory pointer to array
puts v[3] #=> 123456
```

You could also use `AbstractMemory#get_int32` method:

```
size_of_int = 4 # size of int32 in bytes
offset = 0
v = TestModule.TestData
v[3 * size_of_int].get_int32(offset) #=> 123456
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never called C/C++ from Ruby myself, but based on the documentation it looks like you have to call `read_string` and then convert it to an int:

```
v[3].read_string.to_i
```

Hope this helps.